# Xcopy /O /X throwing access denied error on command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, filesystems, fileshare

I'm using below command to create new folder by copying contents of the existing folder and command prompt throws Access Denied error.

**Command:**

```
C:\Users\Kundur.Rudresh>Xcopy C:\test D:\test /O /X /H /K
```

Please let me know do i need to give any permissions.? especially for below points.?

1. /O   Copies file ownership and ACL information.
2. /X   Copies file audit settings (implies /O).

If remove /O and /X from command, which works fine and folder will be created.

[image]

Comment: The problem is most likely that the (your) user doesn't have permission to change the NTFS ACLs ("file/directory permissions") for the target. If you instruct XCOPY to copy the permissions it needs to apply those on the target of course, which it seems it cannot do.

Comment: If you open up a Command Prompt window, type `xcopy /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, you should see that there is a `/I` option you can use to prevent the file or directory prompt. You should also note the using the `/X` option specifically states that it already implies the `/O` option, _(so there is no need to use both)_. `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "C:\test\*" "D:\test\" /HIKX`. As for permission changes, you'd need to ensure that the privileges of the user are sufficient to be able to do so too.

Comment: @Compo **C:\Users\Kundur.Rudresh>Xcopy C:\test D:\test /O /X /H /K** which executes when i select command prompt as Administrator. and this this cmd script is working fine on one of the machine(past many years). and this issue is related to particular system which is newly created.

Comment: And still, @RudreshKundur, you've completely ignored the advice I provided, and which was also included in Wisblade's existing answer. Please do not ignore advice, try it, `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "C:\test\*" "D:\test\" /HIKOX`, then comment accordingly.

Comment: @Compo Thank you very much.. i have executed `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "C:\test\*" "D:\test\" /HIKOX` and received 'Access Denied' and even i have executed the Wisblade's answer and output is same.

Comment: If the user is copying a file, its ownership and ACL information, then they must have full permissions to do that. Clearly the inclusion of the `/I` option, as advised in both my comment and Wizblade's answer has solved your asked question. Try the command without the `/O` option, as offered in my initial comment. If that fails too then permissions to copy the file are your issue, if it copies, then the issue is with copying the ownership and ACL information with it.

Comment: @Compo I have tried by excluding `/O` and issue remains same **Access Denied**

not sure which permission i'm missing (i have given full access to User) and which works only on CMD run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/I` to your `xcopy` parameters. Check `xcopy /?` for details.

```
Xcopy C:\test D:\test /I /O /X /H /K
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have executed `Xcopy C:\test D:\test /I /O /X /H /K` and received same Access Denied 0 File(s) Copied screen..

Comment: @RudreshKundur So it wasn't an artifact caused by the file/directory question... Are you able to really access / read **ALL** files in source folder, and can you write something in destination folder, too? Did you tried the `/G` switch? in addition to all other required switches? You may have either a symlink to a file you can't touch, or an encrypted file...

Comment: tried /G and it didn't worked, everything works only as CDM Administrator